# Acceleration of this Atwood machine configuration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

In the diagram the fixed pulley is ideal and the moving pulley is not

Therefore the tensions holding the movable pulley are different

My question is if the acceleration of the block is $a$ what is the acceleration of the movable pulley?

I'm able to comprehend it is $a/2$ when the movable pulley is ideal (with mass)

But here it's not :(

Comment: When the movable pulley is ideal and massless, there would be no Tension in string as for Tension, you need something to "strain"  or "pull" the string, (which is usually the weight of the pulley).

Comment: @TonyStark my bad added it

Comment: That the acceleration is $a/2$ is a purely *kinematic* property following only from the geometry of the situation. Masses and tensions have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @mike stone but with a difference in tensions the movable pulley won't move downwards linearly it will deveate a little towards the string with greater tension.where have I flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine only the pulley moving up by a distance of $x$, while the string remains as it is. Now from both sides of the pulley, you'll see that $x$ length of the string has been freed. So, in order to make the string taut around the pulley, the block will have to move left by a distance of $2x$.

It follows that if the block moves a distance $x$, the pulley will move a distance $\frac{x}{2}$. Thus, if the block has an acceleration $a$, the pulley will have acceleration $\frac{a}{2}$,

Comment: I have understood that part ,my question is if this is also applicable in a situation where tensions are different like this one .

Comment: In the situation that i described to you, I have not made any assumption about the pulley being ideal. This is applicable in all cases.

Comment: Can u increase my reputation I want to vote @dnaik